# OpenCv Error: Function Not Implemented

Tags: opencv

I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/robik/Downloads/Java/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 275
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what(): /home/robik/Downloads/Java/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:275: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

Aborted
```

libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config both are installed but I still get the error. What is wrong?

I followed the steps at http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/...-ubuntu-11-04/
still doesn't help.

Comment: your link needs to be fixed, also make sure you're linking against libopencv_highghui. please also list the command that you're currently using to compile. normally pkg-config should take care of this

Comment: I'm using g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`